# invalid enum value in field returnPolicyCategory

Tags: schema

I have `hasMerchantReturnPolicy` in Offer of a Product. However, when I tested on Google tool, its said "invalid enum value in field returnPolicyCategory"

```
<div property="schema:hasMerchantReturnPolicy" typeof="schema:MerchantReturnPolicy">
  <div property="schema:returnPolicyCategory" typeof="schema:ReturnPolicyCategory">
    <span property="schema:name">MerchantReturnNotPermitted</span>
  </div>
  <div property="schema:applicableCountry" typeof="schema:Country">
    <span property="schema:name">JP</span>
  </div>
</div>
```